How to find the row coordinate of a specific cell in excel using python

Language: Python (version 3.12)
Packages tried: OpenPyxl and
Pandas

Task: Within a workbook I'm trying to find an instance of a specific year (input) within a column called "Year". From there I'm trying to get the exact row value (integer), so I can update other columns in that row.
Unfortunately I can't find a method to determine the row coordinate when entering the cell value I'm searching for. I've looked at pandas, but finding one where the year can be entered is not leading me anywhere. It seems pandas works great if you know the coordinate or total numbers of rows/columns, but not the coordinate of a specific cell based on a search criteria.
To expand:
I would like to search for an specific year (user input = 2023), so it will return the row coordinate. I want to then have the user fill out the amount paid, with which the program can then calculate the net pay for that year as well as the remaining amount and interest due the year after.

I've tried the code as found here: openpyxl module (Python): how can I get the coordinates of a cell when I know the string value of that cell?
However running it gets hung up on the [-1] within the following line:
 _row_idx = _row_processor[-1]


Where is the code you are using to find the cell? Then we can tell you what object(s) can provide the row.  With Openpyxl for example if you have made the determination that cell 'F3' is the cell that holds the value '2023' the ws['F3'].row will return the row (where ws is the 'worksheet' object). But you can also so see that the row is in the co-ordinate. If your iterating with iter_rows or iter_cols you can again get the the row of the cell as shown in the answer from @kb2136 but also can just the top level item col. Again with @kb2136 answer as an example. col[0].row.

Please include your own code

Have you tried iter_cols?
for col in wb_object[ws_name].iter_cols(min_col=6, max_col=6, min_row=2):
    for cell in col:
        if cell.value == 2023:
            row_idx = cell.row
            break
            

